# I'm not able to get this code to print what's needed. I think my functions are coded incorrectly

Tags: python, function, syntax

Below is the code I'm having issues with, I can't seem to get this to print what is needed and am receiving the error:

```
'non-empty format string passed to object.__format__'
```

This is the code, it seems to be an issue with my function statements that aren't carrying through to the final *displayAns* to print out the last statement informing ***whomever*** what type of driver they are

```
def main():
    customerName = input('Name of the customer: ')

    customerAge = int(input('Age of the customer: '))

    customerViolations = int(input('Customer\'s number of traffice violations: '))

    price = calcPrice(customerAge, customerViolations)
    code = riskCode(customerViolations)
    displayAns(customerName, price, code)


def calcPrice(customerAge, customerViolations):
    if customerAge < 25:
        if customerViolations >= 4:
            calcPrice = 480
        if customerViolations == 3:
            calcPrice = 450
        if customerViolations == 2:
            calcPrice = 405
        if customerViolations == 1:
            calcPrice = 380
        if customerViolations == 0:
            calcPrice = 325
        if customerViolations < 0:
            calcPrice = 'Invalid Violations Entry'
    elif customerAge >= 25:
        if customerViolations >= 4:
            calcPrice = 410
        if customerViolations == 3:
            calcPrice = 390
        if customerViolations == 2:
            calcPrice = 365
        if customerViolations == 1:
            calcPrice = 315
        if customerViolations == 0:
            calcPrice = 275
        if customerViolations < 0:
            calcPrice = 'Invalid Age or Violations Entry'

def riskCode(customerViolations):
    if customerViolations >= 4:
        riskCode = 'High'
    if customerViolations == 3:
        riskCode = 'Moderate'
    if customerViolations == 2:
        riskCode = 'Moderate'
    if customerViolations == 1:
        riskCode = 'Low'
    if customerViolations == 0:
        riskCode = 'No'
    if customerViolations < 0:
        riskCode = 'Invalid Violations Entry'


def displayAns(customerName, price, code):
    print(customerName, ' as a ', code, 'risk driver, your insurance will cost $', format(price, '.2f'), sep = '')


main()
```

Comment: I suggest you read up on functions: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions. Note that the [mcve] to recreate your error is simply: `format(None, '.2f')`.

Comment: You could also simplify significantly with a dictionary mapping e.g. `{0: 325, 1: 380, ...}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def calcPrice(customerAge, customerViolations):
    if customerAge < 25:
        if customerViolations >= 4:
            calcPrice = 480
```

You do not return values from a function by doing `function_name = value`. You need to use the `return` statement.

```
def calcPrice(customerAge, customerViolations):
    if customerAge < 25:
        if customerViolations >= 4:
            return 480
        if customerViolations == 3:
            return 450
        #etc
```

Comment: changed all of the 'calcPrice' and 'riskCode' to return and it's running exactly as needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
customerName = raw_input('Name of the customer: ')

customerAge = int(input('Age of the customer: '))

customerViolations = int(input('Customer\'s number of traffice violations: '))

price = calcPrice(customerAge, customerViolations)
code = riskCode(customerViolations)
displayAns(customerName, price, code)


def calcPrice(customerAge, customerViolations):
if customerAge < 25:
    if customerViolations >= 4:
        returncalcPrice = 480
    if customerViolations == 3:
        calcPrice = 450
    if customerViolations == 2:
        calcPrice = 405
    if customerViolations == 1:
        calcPrice = 380
    if customerViolations == 0:
        calcPrice = 325
    if customerViolations < 0:
        calcPrice = 'Invalid Violations Entry'
elif customerAge >= 25:
    if customerViolations >= 4:
        calcPrice = 410
    if customerViolations == 3:
        calcPrice = 390
    if customerViolations == 2:
        calcPrice = 365
    if customerViolations == 1:
        calcPrice = 315
    if customerViolations == 0:
        calcPrice = 275
    if customerViolations < 0:
        calcPrice = 'Invalid Age or Violations Entry'
def riskCode(customerViolations):
if customerViolations >= 4:
    return 'High'
if customerViolations == 3:
    return 'Moderate'
if customerViolations == 2:
    return 'Moderate'
if customerViolations == 1:
    return 'Low'
if customerViolations == 0:
    return 'No'
if customerViolations < 0:
    return 'Invalid Violations Entry'


def displayAns(customerName, price, code):
print(customerName, ' as a ', code, 'risk driver, your insurance will cost $',format((price), '.2'), ' ')


main()
```

Here. I think fixed.

Comment: Given that you've only added redundant parentheses and broken the layout, I doubt it.